# How to get cookie and session outside of controller in beego

Tags: go, cookies, controller, beego

I wanna get and set cookie in my service file, but the code "ctx.SetCookie()" always get error "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference", please help me, thanks in advance

I have tried two methods to deal this problem,but there is still something wrong with it

method 1:

```
type security struct {
    beego.Controller
}
...
func (s security) CheckToken(){
    ...

    ctx.SetCookie("token","xxxxxxxx")
}
```

methos 2:

```
import "github.com/astaxie/beego/context"

func (s security) CheckToken(){
    ...
    ctx := context.NewContext()
    ctx.SetCookie("token","xxxxxxxx")
}
```

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x832639]

Comment: The [controller's context](https://godoc.org/github.com/astaxie/beego#Controller.Ctx) is required to set and get cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Set cookie can be done via `.SetCookie()` method of beego context object. The context object itself is accessible via any controller that embed `beego.Controller`.

```golang
func (c *MainController) SetToken() {
    c.Ctx.SetCookie("token", "xxxxxxxx")
}

func (c *MainController) GetToken() {
    cookieValue := c.Ctx.GetCookie("token")
    fmt.Println(cookieValue)
}
```

Doc https://beego.me/docs/module/context.md

#### Update #1

> I wanna to set cookie outside of controller

What you need to do is pass the context object of the controller into the particular function. For example:

```
package models

import "github.com/astaxie/beego/context"

func SetCookieFromHere(ctx *context.Context) {
    ctx.SetCookie("token", "xxxxxxxx")
}
```

```golang
package controllers

import "yourpackage/models"

func (c *MainController) SetToken() {
    models.SetCookieFromHere(c.Ctx)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  but I wanna to set cookie outside of controller , do you have any other methods recommended

Comment: @Hugo.Huang you need to pass the context object into the model. see updated answer

Comment: How to use function SetCookieFromHere outside of controller? I get a error "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" when I use it in my service or util file.

Answer (score 1):

You can set via beego filter.

```
var SetCookie = func(ctx *context.Context) {
    ctx.SetCookie("token", "xxxxxxxx")
}

beego.InsertFilter("/*", beego.BeforeRouter, SetCookie)
```